# NSWindow moving not smoothly after upgrade to macos Sierra

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, macos-sierra

I've an application which is NSWindow that being created with

```
init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask: NSWindowStyleMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType, defer: Bool)
```

and being moved programmatically with

```
[NSWindow setFrame:NSRect];
```

After upgrading my os x to Sierra I'm having strange behavior when moving the window. It doesn't move smoothly and leave sort of black tail.

Any ideas what may be the root cause and how to fix this?